# HTML disabled attribute does not work with onChange

Tags: html, select, onchange

I have a long form with inter dependencies on how various fields are enabled/disabled. Below mentioned field `Othervaccination_card_available` is supposed to be disabled when the form loads and is enabled when a previous select value is set. And when `Othervaccination_card_available` is set, it is supposed to enable a third field via onchange function. However, when the form loads, I can see that `Othervaccination_card_available` still enabled. When I remove the `onchange` function, it gets disabled when the form loads as expected. Is there something evidently wrong in my code?

```
<select id="Othervaccination_card_available" 
    name="Othervaccination_card_available" 
    class="validate" 
    onchange = "enable_vaccination_card('Othervaccination_card_available', 'Other_vaccination_card_no', 'Other_vaccination_card_verified');"  
    disabled>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select>

function enable_vaccination_card(vaccination_card_available_id, vaccination_card_no_id,vaccination_card_verified_id){
  var select_vaccination_available = 
  document.getElementById(vaccination_card_available_id);
  var input_vaccination_card_no = 
  document.getElementById(vaccination_card_no_id);
  var select_vaccination_card_verified = 
  document.getElementById(vaccination_card_verified_id);
  if (select_vaccination_available.value == "No") {
   select_vaccination_card_verified.value = "No";
   select_vaccination_card_verified.disabled = true;
   input_vaccination_card_no.disabled = true;
  }
  else {
   select_vaccination_card_verified.value = "";
   select_vaccination_card_verified.disabled = false;
   input_vaccination_card_no.disabled = false;
  }
  $("#" + vaccination_card_verified_id).formSelect();
  M.updateTextFields();
}
```

Comment: Can you give us your js code?

Comment: Please refer [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I added JS as requested,thanks